# How to get only enabled products in the low stock collection in Magento

Tags: php, mysql, magento, zend-framework, orm

I'm trying to get only enabled products in my low stock collection.

My code looks like this:

```
/** @var $collection Mage_Reports_Model_Resource_Product_Lowstock_Collection  */
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_lowstock_collection')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->setStoreId($storeId)
            ->filterByIsQtyProductTypes()
            ->joinInventoryItem('qty')
            ->joinInventoryItem('low_stock_date')
            ->useManageStockFilter($storeId)
            ->useNotifyStockQtyFilter($storeId)
            ->setOrder('qty', Varien_Data_Collection::SORT_ORDER_ASC);
```

But I can't add a filter to the ORM like that :

```
->addAttributeToFiler('status', array('eq' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED))
```

Anyone knows how to do this?

Comment: You made a typo mistake : `addAttributeToFiler` instead of `addAttributeToFilter`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to join the `catalog_product_entity_int` table which holds the status value for each product, to make things easier please make sure of the attribute_id of the status attribute, in my case it is 96. you can check it from your admin panel `Manage Attributes` or from `eav_attribute` table.

Below is the Inner Join to be applied:

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_lowstock_collection')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->setStoreId($storeId)
            ->filterByIsQtyProductTypes()
            ->joinInventoryItem('qty')
            ->joinInventoryItem('low_stock_date')
            ->useManageStockFilter($storeId)
            ->useNotifyStockQtyFilter($storeId)
            ->setOrder('qty', 'asc')
                 ->getSelect()
                 ->join(Mage::getConfig()->getTablePrefix().'catalog_product_entity_int', 'lowstock_inventory_item.product_id ='.Mage::getConfig()->getTablePrefix().'catalog_product_entity_int.entity_id',array('value'))
                 ->where(Mage::getConfig()->getTablePrefix().'catalog_product_entity_int.value=1 AND '.Mage::getConfig()->getTablePrefix().'catalog_product_entity_int.attribute_id=96');
```

And this is the generated SQL query:

```
SELECT `e`.*, `lowstock_inventory_item`.`qty`, `lowstock_inventory_item`.`low_stock_date`, `catalog_product_entity_int`.`value` FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`
 INNER JOIN `cataloginventory_stock_item` AS `lowstock_inventory_item` ON e.entity_id = lowstock_inventory_item.product_id
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` ON lowstock_inventory_item.product_id =catalog_product_entity_int.entity_id WHERE (((`e`.`type_id` = 'simple') OR (`e`.`type_id` = 'virtual') OR (`e`.`type_id` = 'giftcard'))) AND (IF(lowstock_inventory_item.use_config_manage_stock = 1, 1, lowstock_inventory_item.manage_stock) = 1) AND (qty < IF(lowstock_inventory_item.use_config_notify_stock_qty = 1, 1, lowstock_inventory_item.notify_stock_qty)) AND (catalog_product_entity_int.value=1 AND catalog_product_entity_int.attribute_id=96)
```

Comment: Does this work for you? The block doesn't render but I got no error message. Why do you use the (string) ? And I think there have to be a where clause for the storeId as well. The attribute_id is the same for me.

Comment: Sorry, Removed the casting, I was debugging it to check the query.